# Touchmove event is not working in Edge Animate CC

Tags: jquery, touchmove

I am a graphic designer with limited code skill using the latest Edge Animate CC 2015. I wanted to achieve a horizontal parallax effect by moving my stage (actually a year based timeline) with touch/mouse in a kiosk touchscreen (run by Windows touchscreen laptop. I don't want any scroll bar to appear on screen). I watched Paul Trani's parallax effect video on YouTube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wUJ63cBwS1I) and tried the following:

On `compositionReady` code window...

```
this.onMove=function(posX, posY){
timelinecontrol = Number(posX)*2.5;
console.log(timelinecontrol);
sym.stop(timelinecontrol);
}
```

On **touchmove** code window:

```
this.onMove (e.pageX, e.pageY);
```

But it didn't work with the **touchmove** event. However, when I put the last line in **mousemove** code window like paul's original video, it worked as usual.

For record, I have the following script installed:

jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.js
jquery-mobile-1.4.2.min.js
jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js
jquery-2.0.3.min.js

Do you think not using any updated script causing this problem? Is there any HTML 5 incompatibility issue with certain browsers/platform?

I also tried the following code from adobe forum...

```
$(window).on "mousemove touchmove", (e) ->
  touch = undefined
  if e.originalEvent.touches
    touch = e.originalEvent.touches[0]
  pos_x = e.pageX
```

But Edge Animate CC found system syntax error on the first line. Any suggestion how can I adopt this on the latest Edge Animate? I tried 'stage' in place or 'window' but failed.

Answer (score 0):

try using touchstart instead of touchmove event